# How to find the inner half area of a rectangle

Tags: rectangles, area, surface

I have a rectangle, for example width x height = 200 x 100cm. Thus, it has an area of 20,000cm2. The lower left corner has the coordinate (0,0) and the upper right corner has the coordinate (200,100).

I want to split this rectangle into two pieces with equal surface area: the middle half and the outer half, to make a sort of 'doughnut' shape.

I'm struggling to find an easy way to do this. I know that the middle half must have a surface area of 10,000cm2 and I want it to have the same 2:1 aspect ratio as the large rectangle. How do I calculate the correct scaling factor?

By iterating the equation:
(s * 200) * (s * 100) = area
I know that a scaling value around 0.7 is correct, but I don't know why?

When I try to Google solutions to this I get 100s of websites aimed at school children explaining how to calculate the area of a rectangle but nothing more advanced than this.

Comment: Just to be clear: you want the "outer" shape to be a rectangle with a hole in it? And the area of the hole being the same value as the area of the outer shape?

Comment: The exact scaling value is sqrt(2)/2.  That's the solution to sx * sy = (x * y)/2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite simple math. Assume you have a rectangle with sides of length `a` and `b`, with the coordinates of the lower left corner `(x, y)`.

Then the area of that rectangle is `A = a * b`. Now you want to find a rectangle with area `A' = A/2 = a * b / 2` and and sides of length `a'` and `b'` where the condition is `a / b = a' / b'` (ie their aspect ratio is the same). So you have 2 equations

```
I    a' * b'  =  a*b/2
II   a'/b'    =  a/b
```

In this equations, the values for `a` and `b` are known (they are `200` and `100` in your case). Thus you have a linear equation system with 2 variables and 2 equations, which can easily be solved. Solving this, leads to

```
b' = sqrt(b^2/2) = b / sqrt(2)
a' = a / sqrt(2)
```

To find the coordinates `(x', y')` of the lower left corner of the inner rectangle, you have to substract the sides of the inner rectangle from the sides of the outer rectangle, divide that lengths by `2` and add them to the coordinates of the outer rectangle.

```
x' = x + (a - a')/2
y' = y + (b - b')/2
```

A even more generalized solution:

If you want `A' = A / n` with `n` being any positive number, the scaling factor is `1/sqrt(n)`. And thus

```
b' = b / sqrt(n)
a' = a / sqrt(n)
```

And it can easily be seen that

```
a / sqrt(n) * b / sqrt(n) = (a * b) / n = A / n
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. Do you might explaining how you get from equations I and II to the solutions? I don't quite see how you did that even if values a and b are known...

Comment: It's just basic math, solving a system of two linear equations. See for instance https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/economics/algebra/solving-simultaneous-linear-equations.html